# update экранируя кавычки(символы)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Приветствую! 
Необходимо добавить в БД примерно такого вида текст: Водка "Свояк". Получаю только первую часть... Водка :) 
Запрос выглядит так:

```
function updateBar(){
    foreach ($_POST['name'] as $id=>$v)
        $updBar= R::exec( 'UPDATE bar SET `name`="'.$_POST['name'][$id].'",price="'.$_POST['price'][$id].'"
WHERE id="'.$id.'"');
    exit;
}
if (isset($_POST['name']) AND !empty($_POST['name'])) { // если массив не пуст запустим update();
    updateBar();
}
```

-> **Использую ORM redbaenphp** <-
Про функцию mysqli_real_escape_string(), читал. Пробовал так:

```
function updateBar(){
    $link = R::setup('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=Cafe', 'root', '');
    foreach ($_POST['name'] as $id=>$v)
        $updBar= R::exec( 'UPDATE bar SET `name`="'. $link->real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$id]).'",price="'.$_POST['price'][$id].'"
WHERE id="'.$id.'"');
    exit;
}
if (isset($_POST['name']) AND !empty($_POST['name'])) { // если массив не пуст запустим update();
    updateBar();
}
```

...не работает.

Comment: Отучитесь собирать текст запроса в операторе его выполнения. Соберите его в переменной, а потом выполняйте. А в промежутке - выведите текст запроса из переменной да посмотрите, вменяемый запрос Вы хотите отправить на сервер, или дурь несусветную...

Comment: Поясню, запрос рабочий... не умею "взапихнуть" экранирование.

Comment: Внесите указанные изменения в код. Выведенный текст собранного запроса (а не код его сборки) покажите тут. Тогда будет о чём говорить. PS. Экранирование тут не нужно. А нужно - заменить двойную кавычку вокруг литерала в запросе на одинарную.

Answer (score 0):

Перед апдейтом конвертируйте вводные данные при помощи функции php [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace('"','\"',$name);
```

А вот так пробовал?

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте подстановку текста из переменных непосредственно в запрос и тогда экранирование вам вообще не понадобится, интерфейс БД сам обо всем позаботится. Используйте привязку переменных. Примерно так:

```
$updBar= R::exec( 'UPDATE bar SET `name`=?,price=? WHERE id=?',
                  Array($_POST['name'][$id], $_POST['price'][$id], $id)
                );
```

Взято из официальной [документации](http://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/quick_tour)

Comment: Жаль, но не сработало. При попытке добавить к слову что либо в кавычках ничего не происходит. Так же перестал как либо реагировать сам запрос на обновление... проще говоря поломалось.

Comment: @CyberJo И ошибок при этом не выдает ? Вы как то контролируете наличие ошибок и сообщения выводите ? Вообще я потерял пока писал `[$id]` после `[price]` (сейчас уже поправил), вы у себя это поправили, когда копировали ?

Comment: Ошибок на экран не выдавало, по другому не контролировал.

Comment: @CyberJo А вывод ошибок включен ? http://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/debugging

Comment: нет я же только учусь :) Спасибо включил, на экран вывело только это: SELECT `bar`.* FROM `bar` -- keep-cache
resultset: 15 rows

Comment: @CyberJo Ну это select, а update видимо то же должно было выдать. Вы бы попробовали для начала отдельно от основного скрипта небольшую тестовую программу сделать, что бы в ней только update был и там подставить три переменные с предопределенными значениями и посмотреть сработало или нет и может заодно ошибки увидите если они будут

Comment: ну как бы отдельно и лежит в библиотеке со всеми функциями :) Но я вас понял, попробую.